# How to convert a large JSON string to JSON Object?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, performance, spring-resttemplate

My spring application does a rest request to a server and the response from the server is a JSONObject string. The JSON string is very huge(200MB). I want to convert the json string to a JSONObject. Below are my code for conversion:

```
exchange = restTemplate.exchange(Url, HttpMethod.POST, postEntity, String.class);
jsonObject = objectMapper.readValue(exchange.getBody(), JSONObject.class);
```

For a single request, it is taking 3-5 seconds for conversion. But, if there are multiple requests the conversion is taking so much time (60 seconds for 8-10 requests in parallel).
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Seems that you have posted 2 eual questions. I suggest you delete one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that transforming a 200MB chunk of JSON to an object using jackson-databind's `ObjectMapper` will almost always consume a lot of computing time and furthermore huge amounts of memory.

If you don't need the whole object represented by the JSON in memory at a single time, i. e. chunks of it will suffice, I would advise to switch to an approach that utilizes [jackson's streaming API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi). You can combine it with databind on smaller subsets of the JSON, passing the resulting DTOs to some consumer (kind of visitor pattern).

I hope this is of any help for your special use-case.