# Android Studio - Java (JSONObject/JSONArray) Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-studio

Kindly asking for help, I am trying to get a JSON response from an API and the response was **not null** and kinda long because it has a **Base64** encoded picture data [This is the fragment from the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT1iM.png)

and this is the part of the code i use to get the JSON response and convert it to JSONArray

```
        StringRequest reqMasterDataShift = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ActionUrl.LastShift+"/"+siteCode,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray shift = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shift");
                        JSONArray shiftPhoto = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shift_photo"); // Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()

                        Timestamp currentTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

                        ArrayList<ShiftModel> shiftData = new ArrayList<>();
                        shiftData = mapper.readValue(shift.toString(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<ShiftModel>>() {});

                        ArrayList<ShiftPhotoModel> shiftPhotoData = new ArrayList<>();
                        shiftPhotoData = mapper.readValue(shiftPhoto.toString(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<ShiftPhotoModel>>() {}); 
                        .
                        .
                        ...
```

I kindly hope for your help or solution for this problem, and i really appreciate for comments or some suggestion, thanks!

Comment: can you post the whole response body?

Comment: @GuanHongHuang check it here https://pastelink.net/4mvwm1ns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this- First convert the base64 to bitmap and try to place it in imageview

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
  byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
  String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
  imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
  Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

Comment: First of all thankyou for your response for this question, but the main problem is i couldn't configure how to solve the JSONObject converted into string() exception problem

Comment: I think its because of the huge and heavy string it causes actually
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64752148/how-to-convert-a-large-json-string-to-json-object  check this

Comment: owhh i see, seems like the JSON response i get was heavy causing the program slow down, but it actually works just fine if i just ignore the warning, thankyou